# Performing calculation between rows (observations) in your dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

Say I have a dataframe like this:

```
data = structure(list(yaw = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 5), z = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
    x = c(1, 3, 2, 2, 3)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

And I want to perform a calculation between each row (observation) and the row before it and then save this as a new column in the dataframe (or maybe save as a new data set? For example:

```
newdata <- data %>%
mutate(Yaw = Row2Yaw - Row1Yaw) %>%
mutate(hypotenuse = sqrt((Row2X - Row1X)^2 + (Row2Z - Row1Z)^2) %>%
mutate(lane_deviation = sin(Yaw) * hypotenuse)
```

Hence this gives me a lane_deviation value for the difference between these two rows. Ideally I would want to calculate this for every observation (i.e. Row3Yaw - Row2Yaw) etc...)

Is this possible in dplyr or would I need some form of loop? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: just use `lag` or `lead` and your code should work pretty much as is. Or just use `diff`- which should be even easier

Comment: e.g. `Yaw` is just `diff(data$yaw)`. `hypotenuse` is just `sqrt(diff(data$x)^2 + diff(data$z)^2)`, etc.

Comment: @DavidArenburg What would I have to do in order to calculate the difference and then add it to the previous value i.e. calculating lane deviation between Row2 and Row1, then calculating between Row3 and Row2 and add it to the previous value and so on...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `data.table` as well-

```
setDT(data)
data[,hypotenuse:=sqrt((lead(yaw)-yaw)*2 + (lead(yaw)-yaw)*2)]
data[,lane_deviation:=sin(yaw) * hypotenuse]
```

As mentioned in the comments by @David, we can use `lead` function

And using `dplyr`

```
newdata <- data %>%
    mutate(Yaw = lead(yaw)-yaw) %>%
    mutate(hypotenuse = sqrt((lead(yaw)-yaw)^2 + (lead(yaw)-yaw)^2)) %>%
               mutate(lane_deviation = sin(Yaw) * hypotenuse)
```

Comment: What would I have to do in order to calculate the difference like here, and then add it to the previous value i.e. calculating lane deviation between Row2 and Row1, then calculating between Row3 and Row2 and adding it to the previous calculated value and so on...?